# Issue in consuming the certificate chain in corda

Tags: java, certificate, corda, certificate-authority

I want to create a custom CA and have created rootCertficate as mention on [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/create-your-own-certificate-and-ca) using following commands

```
set RANDFILE=rand
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\Binaries\openssl-X64\openssl.cnf
openssl req -new -keyout cakey.pem -out careq.pem
openssl x509 -signkey cakey.pem -req -days 3650 -in careq.pem -out caroot.cer -extensions v3_ca
```

I then use this certificate as root to sign and create other certificates using java program

```
public static X509Certificate signCertificateSigningRequest(
            PKCS10CertificationRequest jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest, KeyPair keyPair, String requestId,
            X509Certificate serverCert) throws Exception
    {
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo pkInfo = jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        PublicKey pubKey = converter.getPublicKey(pkInfo);
        X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(serverCert, new BigInteger("1"), // serial
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L),
                jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest.getSubject(), pubKey
        ).addExtension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.19"), false, new BasicConstraints(false)
        // true if it is allowed to sign other certs
        ).addExtension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.15"), true, new X509KeyUsage(X509KeyUsage.digitalSignature
                | X509KeyUsage.nonRepudiation | X509KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | X509KeyUsage.dataEncipherment));

        AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
        // ContentSigner sigGen = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId,
        // digAlgId).build(asymmetricKeyParameter);
        ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").build(keyPair.getPrivate());

        X509CertificateHolder x509CertificateHolder = certificateBuilder.build(sigGen);
        Certificate eeX509CertificateStructure = x509CertificateHolder.toASN1Structure();
        // Read Certificate
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
        InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(eeX509CertificateStructure.getEncoded());
        X509Certificate signedCertificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(is1);
        FileSystemUtility.saveCertificate(signedCertificate.getEncoded(), serverCert.getEncoded(), requestId);
        return signedCertificate;
    }
```

Where root certificate is picked using:

```
public static X509Certificate getServerCertificate() throws Exception
    {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
        return (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(
                new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/varun/Desktop/cert/CA/caroot.cer")));
    }
```

But when I send both the certificate at receiver end and it tries to validate it i get following error:

**Issue 1**

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: CA key usage check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.KeyChecker.verifyCAKeyUsage(KeyChecker.java:159) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.KeyChecker.check(KeyChecker.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:219) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:347) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:249) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1268) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1176) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
```

Issue 1 is **resolved**

**Issue 2**

```
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:449) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:219) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: You need to add to the CA certificate the "Certificate signing" key usage

Comment: @pedrofb-how is that done?

Comment: all I know is that I followed this guide https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html then for BouncyCastle the code you got here worked (although if you want to sign certs with this cert, then you should set `basic constraint` to `true` most likely)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to the CA certificate the "Certificate signing" key usage. Ensure that the [v3_ca] section of the OpenSSL conf file includes `keyUsage = keyCertSign`

```
[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
```

See a full example here: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html

Comment: have you verified that the generated certificate does indeed have the required keyUsage?

Comment: Seems you are listing extendedKeyUsage. I can't see `keyCertSign` in your list. Are you listing it correctly? Your script includes `-extensions v3_ca`, so I assumed you are using a [ v3_ca ] section. Ensure you are applying it

Comment: Using openssl on windows should not be a problem. Use `openssl x509 -in caroot.cer -text -noout` to print the certification info. Look at  `X509v3 Key Usage` and `X509v3 Basic Constraints`

Comment: client side is an open source implementation called `Corda`

Added the new issue i am facing now

Comment: The second error is probably due to the server certificate is not correctly signed by the CA. It is an issue with the bouncycastle code not related with the first one. I will take a look later

Comment: thanks @pedrofb for the help you are providing, really appreciated... also if possible share me some link to understand the certificates in details

Comment: Do we need to use same private key for CA and new certificate? I have used different

Comment: No, in any case. The CA's private key must be used only to sign the certificates issued and must be kept secure. The private key of the final certificate is generated in the client and does not even have to be known by the CA

Comment: I'm not sure what the reason for your second problem is. I would have to debug the code but I suspect that you are not adding the certification chain to the certificate. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477679/sign-csr-with-bouncycastle/37983438#37983438), it is not accepted but it is extracted from a working example

Comment: does the root certficaite needs to be part of keystore of CA? cant we simply read the cert file and send it across

Comment: The CA does not owns the certificate private key, so only can maintain a copy of the issued certificate. The certificate does not need to be stored in the keystore. You only need to send the issued certificate to the client, but as I commented before, the generated certificate should include also the certification chain (in your case the CA certificate)

Comment: ya did that, but after that too getting `Issue #2`

Comment: can you pleae help me on this i tried your link but getting the same error

Comment: could you post a sample certificate with a sample CA to analyze it?