# Sign CSR with JAVA security library / No BC usage

Tags: csr, java-security

I wanted to know if there is a way to sign CSR with the Java security library. We are trying to avoid to use Bouncy Castle library. We don't wont any additional dependency in our project.

Our CSR, CA private and pulic key are in PEM format.

Regards,

Comment: You can try this https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1464167276-Generating-CSR-using-Java

Comment: The link shows how to generate CSR in pkcs10. We are ok with that, we want to sign that CSR. Generally, It's the step after the CSR generation

Comment: The linked code shows how to build and sign the CSR. See `pkcs10.encodeAndSign(x500Name, sig)`

Comment: The `pkcs10.encodeAndSign(x500Name, sig)` is signing the CSR with the private key of the of the person issuing the request:
`sig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());`
 
We wanted to sign it with the CA keypair (private key in fact) and the output should be a X509 Certificate.

Without BouncyCastle if possible, of course

Comment: Your question may confuse. A CSR is signed by the requestor, not by the CA. The CA extracts the public key,, some additional information such as the CN and verifies the signature. After this generates a new certificate containing the public key and signs it using CA's private key. Here you have an old answer with an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/37983438/6371459. I do not feel strong enough to do it without bouncycastle

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's usually common to say "Sign CSR" referring to the process of generating a certificate based on the public key included in a CSR. Any way, we are already doing that with bouncy castle. We are studying the case to do it without BC dependency...

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard Java API to do that. However, you can use the -certreq option of the keytool utility to create CSRs using private keys stored in a keystore.

Comment: I wanted to do it programatically, so with a java code inside our application. ..